# Login form in Codeigniter problems

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to make Login form using codeigniter, but my HTML code for login form doesn't work. I'm still trying to learn Codeigniter and I can't get what's the problem, why the form doesn't load

This is my html code for login form inside `views` folder :

```html
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

 <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="loginmodal-container">
    <?php
    if (!empty($login_errors)) {
     ?><h1>We could not log you in</h1><br /><?php
    } else {
     ?><h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br /><?php
    }
    ?>
    <form id="login" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login">
     <input type="text"     name="login_email"    placeholder="Username" />
     <input type="password" name="login_password" placeholder="Password" />
     <input type="submit"   name="login_submit"   class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login" />
    </form>

    <div class="login-help">
     <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register">Register</a> - <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>reset_password">Forgot Password</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<?php
if (!empty($login_errors) || isset($display_login)) {
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#login-modal').modal('show');
 </script>
 <?php
}
?>
```

And here is the code from `controller` where i pass login form :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function index(){
  $data['title']= 'My Blog';

  $this->load->model('Structure_model');
  $footer = $this->Structure_model->get_footer_details();

  $data['login'] = $this->load->view('login_view', NULL, TRUE);

  $this->load->view('header', $data);
  $this->load->view('welcome_message');
  $this->load->view('footer', $footer);
 }
}
```

And also header who is inside `views` folder :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>

<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/jquery/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-expand-lg">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand " id="logo" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">MiceX</a>
  </div>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-left: 10% ;">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>rent_vehicle">Vehicle Selection</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <?php
   if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true ) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer_account"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . " " . $_SESSION['last_name']; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>customer_account"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> Account</a></li>
    <?php
    if ($_SESSION['access_level'] == 100) {
     ?><li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin_account"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Admin Account</a></li><?php
    }
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/logout"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o"></i> Logout</a></li>
    <?php
   } else {
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o"></i> Login</a></li>
    <?php
   }

   if ( isset($_SESSION['cart_total']) ) {
    ?><li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> $<?php echo $_SESSION['cart_total']; ?></a></li><?php
   }
   ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<?php echo $login; ?>
```

The Login form I pass it into header. When I load the page I can see the navbar and when I click to Login button nothing happends.  I can't get why it doesn't show up the Login form.
There's no errors.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try debug this. for first see HTML source of generated page and check that modal window with login form are inserted.

Comment: I already do that.

Comment: Next you can check that all .js files loaded without errors. There is like to bootstrap code for show modal window. And it not working.